# Sort multidimensional array by one value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that contains data of basketball players and their statistics. I want to sort this array by one of the statistic categories. How can I sort the array?

As a small example, let's use the following three arrays that are part of the bigger array:

```
$playername = array();
$team = array();
$pts = array();
```

They get added to the playerdata array:

```
$data = array(
     'playername' => $playername,
     'team' => $team,
     'pts' => $pts
);
```

So for example the data array consists of three players:

- [0] -> player A, team A, 10
- [1] -> player B, team B, 20
- [2] -> player C, team C, 5

I now want to sort the array `$data` by the content of the `$pts` array, so that in the end the order of `$data` is:

- [0] -> player B, team B, 20
- [1] -> player A, team A, 10
- [2] -> player C, team C, 5

How can I achieve this?

edit: I tried using a solution that I read in another question/answer but could not really get it to do what I want:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['pts'] <=> $b['pts'];
});
```

Comment: See [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: I read about usort() in other questions/answer, but cannot really get it to work.

I used what was proposed somewhere else. I edited the code into my question.

Comment: The `order` key doesn't exist in your array, try `pts`

Comment: That was just a copy paste error when copying it into here. I tried it with pts, still not working. Values are still in their default order and not ordered by 'pts' and also I cannot use `$data['playername'][$i]` anymore to access the value for playername.

Comment: Okay, I investigated it: He actually did "sort" something. But instead of ordering by the value of 'pts' he instead rearranged the order of the arrays so instead of 'playername', 'team', 'pts' the order is now 'playername', 'pts', 'team'.

Comment: I don't think your array is built correctly. It contains three unrelated arrays so this is why sorting will only rearrange the sub-arrays. A proper way to add to the array will be `$data[] = ['playername'=>'A', 'team'=>'A',  'pts'=>10];` and so on. This way your sort function will work.

Comment: and how to achieve this when filling the array with data from a sql query?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing the structure of the query results.

Comment: Okay, your assumption was on point. I built the `$data` array using a `for` clause and added each player and his information one by one. Now it works with usort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I get your data array right, but assuming it looks like this:

```
$data = [

    [
        'playername' =>'Player A',
        'team' => 'Team A',
        'pts' => 10
    ],
    [
        'playername' =>'Player B',
        'team' => 'Team B',
        'pts' => 20
    ],
    [
        'playername' =>'Player C',
        'team' => 'Team C',
        'pts' => 5
    ],
];
```

With [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), you'd sort it like this:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {

    if ($a['pts'] == $b['pts']) {
    
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['pts'] < $b['pts']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

You can play around with the code on [PHPSandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/withered-frost-edog-unnjn).

If you like to sort the players by their ascending points, just flip the sorting expression around:

```
return ($a['pts'] < $b['pts']) ? -1 : 1;
```

If you want to sort by player or team name, just replace the sorting criteria:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {

    if ($a['team'] == $b['team']) {
    
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['team'] < $b['team']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Use the spaceship operator as a shorthand notation:

```
return $a['pts'] <=> $b['pts']; // Ascending
return $b['pts'] <=> $a['pts']; // Descending
```

Comment: Great, my pleasure. Maybe you'd consider to accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$players = [
    ['playername' =>'Player A','team' => 'Team A','pts' => 10],
    ['playername' =>'Player B','team' => 'Team B','pts' => 20],
    ['playername' =>'Player C','team' => 'Team C','pts' => 5]
];
function pointsASC($player1, $player2){
    if ($player1['pts'] == $player2['pts']) {
        return 0;
    }elseif($player1['pts'] < $player2['pts']){
        return 1;
    }elseif($player1['pts'] > $player2['pts']){
        return -1;
    }
}
usort($players,'pointsASC');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($players);
/*
[
    ['playername' =>'Player B','team' => 'Team B','pts' => 20],
    ['playername' =>'Player A','team' => 'Team A','pts' => 10],
    ['playername' =>'Player C','team' => 'Team C','pts' => 5]
];
*/
```