# How to sort php multidimensional array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

How to sort php array by second key or how to reformat that array to make it possible
I want to order array by 1,2 (second key)

(
[0] =>  Array
(
[1] => Array
(
[hashtag] => a7e87329b5eab8578f4f1098a152d6f4
[title] => Flower
[order] => 3
)
)

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array 
            (
            [hashtag] => b24ce0cd392a5b0b8dedc66c25213594
            [title] => Free
            [order] => 2
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array 
            (
            [hashtag] => e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b
            [title] => Ready
            [order] => 1
            )
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array 
            (
            [hashtag] => e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b
            [title] => Ready
            [order] => 1
            )
    )
```

)

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923464/sort-multidimensional-array-by-one-value/66924351

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

function sorting($arr) {
  for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j < count($arr)-$j-1; $j++) {
      if (key($arr[$j]) > key($arr[$j+1])) {
        $tmp = $arr[$j];
        $arr[$j] = $arr[$j+1];
        $arr[$j+1] = $tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  return $arr;
}

$testArray = array(
  0 => array(
        2 => array
            (
            "hashtag" => "b24ce0cd392a5b0b8dedc66c25213594",
            "title" => "Free",
            "order" => 2
            )
    ),
  1 => array(
        1 => array
            (
            "hashtag" => "e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b",
            "title" => "Ready",
            "order" => 1
            )
    ),
  2 => array(
        2 => array
            (
            "hashtag" => "e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b",
            "title" => "Ready",
            "order" => 1
            )
    ));

echo var_dump(sorting($testArray));

?>
```

Comment: I've add one extra row to array and its doesn't sort .... (tried at real array its doesnt work too) I've easy solution array input data comes from mysql so i can order by that key it right in SQL ...  https://paiza.io/projects/FMosW-wB8wg7n8MtSyoPgw